# Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #8

Tags: magento2

I am new to magento I am trying to integrate paytm payment gateway after followed all the steps I got blank screen in checkout page . i am using Magento version 2.4.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.paytm.com/docs/magento/

Comment: hi @RkRathod i have tried all the steps using above document only

Comment: Are you getting errors in de var/log files? If so what errors are you getting?

Comment: main.CRITICAL: Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #8 [ <required> One97\Paytm\Helper\Data $helper ] of One97\Paytm\Model\Paytm class [] []

this is the error i am getting